# Test ngIf elements in jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have a control enclosed in ngIf, on running ng test, elements inside ngIf is not rendered in jasmine view.

spec.ts

```
 it('Master card', () => {
    component.getCardType('5453010330100560');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.cardType).toBe('MSCD');
  });
```

components.ts

```
getCardType(number) {
  //I have a function call here 
    this.getMonths();
    ....
}
```

Get months function

```
getMonths() {
    const year = this.ipExpiryYear.nativeElement;
    ....
}
```

viewChild element ref of the element

```
@ViewChild('expiryYear') ipExpiryYear: ElementRef;
```

HTML file

```
 <select #expiryYear  *ngIf="!isMobileView" >
    <option disabled hidden [value]="undefined"></option>
 </select>
```

I have also tried initialize the ngIf variable

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CardComponent);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.isMobileView = false;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

When I`m running ng test, I`m getting error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined, Please help to resolve this

Comment: seems like getCardType is called before the view is setup

Comment: I have also tried setting up  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CardComponent);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.isMobileView = false;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

Comment: @manomanoj: You should entire component. that would help us understand the sequence of function calls and rendering